# Помогите составить алгоритм задачи

Tags: java, алгоритм

Задается последовательность из девяти цифр, от 0 до 9. Каждая цифра указывает высоту стены.

Представим: если вылить на эту конструкцию воду, то некоторое количество воды задержится между стенками.

Допустим:  квадрат 1 х 1 - содержит в себе объем воды,  равный одному литру.

Задание: написать программу с алгоритмом,  который рассчитывал бы сохраняемый между стенками объем воды.

Начальная последовательность цифр задается строкой с разделителем в виде знака",".

Comment: вам с какой сложностью алгоритм нужен?

Comment: @pavel без разницы.

Comment: Похожий вопрос (ответ на Питоне): [Algorithm to solve for water accumulation given building heights](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27652073/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Ну если всё равно на сложность, тогда лобовая очередь. Формально нужно найти элемент, у которого все соседи либо больше, либо равны но тогда от них дальше искать.

1. Берём элемент (любой, лучше с меньших начинать).
2. Проверяем что он подходит:

   взять всех соседей, если сосед меньше то не подходит иначе
        если сосед равен то проверить соседа
        иначе нечего.
3. Увеличить значения во всех одинаковых из пункта 2 на 1.
4. Перейти к пукнту 1.

P.S. на краю нули.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[] myIntArray = {2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 7, 6}; 
        System.out.println(calculateVolume(myIntArray));
    }

    public static int calculateVolume(int[] land) {

        int leftMax = 0;
        int rightMax = 0;
        int left = 0;
        int right = land.length - 1;
        int volume = 0;

        while(left < right) {
            if(land[left] > leftMax) {
                leftMax = land[left];
            }
            if(land[right] > rightMax) {
                rightMax = land[right];
            }
            if(leftMax >= rightMax) {
                volume += rightMax - land[right];
                right--;
            } else {
                volume += leftMax - land[left];
                left++;
            }
        }
        return volume;
    }
}
```